# How to populate a Dictionary using multiple keys

Tags: c#, dictionary, foreach

I just began working with Dictionary in C# and I can not figure out how to create a Dictionary that has this form:

```
{
  "Lifecycle": [
      {
          "default_value": "45",
          "group_name": "Lifecycle",
          "setting_value": "45",
          "setting_description": "Åldersavdrag gräns"
       },
       {
          "default_value": "2.5",
          "group_name": "Lifecycle",
          "setting_value": "2.5",
          "setting_description": "Åldersavdrag procent",
       },
  ],
},
{
  "Test": [
      {
          "default_value": "0",
          "group_name": "Test",
          "setting_value": "0",
          "setting_description": "Administration fee",
       }
  ],
}
```

My code right now look like this:

The class representing the object:

```
public class Configuration
{
  public string default_value { get; set; }
  public string group_name { get; set; }
  public string setting_value { get; set; }
  public string setting_description { get; set; }
}

public class Configurations
{
  public List<Configuration> configurations;
        
}
```

In my Main class I am creating new configurations object and add them to the configurations List:

```
Configuration configuration1 = new Configuration()
{
  default_value = "45",
  group_name= "Lifecycle",
  setting_value= "45",
  setting_description= "Medicinsk invaliditet - Åldersavdrag gräns",
};

Configuration configuration2 = new Configuration()
{
  default_value = "2.5",
  group_name = "Lifecycle",
  setting_value = "2.5",
  setting_description = "Medicinsk invaliditet - Åldersavdrag procent"
};

Configuration configuration3 = new Configuration()
{
  default_value = "0",
  group_name = "Test",
  setting_value = "0",
  setting_description = "Administration fee",
};

List<Configuration> configurations = new List<Configuration>();
configurations.Add(configuration1);
configurations.Add(configuration2);
configurations.Add(configuration3);
```

Then in a foreach-loop I try to create the Dictionary like this:

```
foreach (Configuration config in configurations)
{
  Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
  configuration.default_value = config.default_value;
  configuration.group_name = config.group_name;
  configuration.setting_value = config.setting_value;
  configuration.setting_description = config.setting_description;
                
  configs.configurations.Add(configuration);
  Dictionary<string, List<Configuration>> configurationDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<Configuration>>();
  
  configurationDictionary.Add(config.group_name, configs.configurations);

}
```

But it doesn't work, what I get in the Dictionary is this:

```
{
  "Test": [
    {
      "default_value": "45",
      "group_name": "Lifecycle",
      "setting_value": "45",
      "setting_description": "Medicinsk invaliditet - Åldersavdrag gräns"
    },
    {
      "default_value": "2.5",
      "group_name": "Lifecycle",
      "setting_value": "2.5",
      "setting_description": "Medicinsk invaliditet - Åldersavdrag procent"
    },
    {
      "default_value": "0",
      "group_name": "Test",
      "setting_value": "0",
      "setting_description": "Administration fee"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to generate a Dictionary with the form like in the first code snippet?

Comment: Use LINQ's `GroupBy` function.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need to get the following definition out of the loop

```
Dictionary<string, List<Configuration>> configurationDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<Configuration>>();
configurationDictionary.Add(config.group_name, configs.configurations);
```

Edit:

```
var configurationDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<Configuration>>();
foreach (Configuration config in configurations) {
    var sublist = configurations.Where(x=>x.group_name.Equals(config.group_name)).ToList();
    configurationDictionary.Add(config.group_name, sublist);
}
```

Comment: But if I move the configurationDictioray.Add... line outside the loop how can I get the group_name value?

Comment: What I want to tell you is that you define the configurationDictionary variable inside the loop and you never use it.